# extract string from string in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this query:-

```
 select col_str,
 getVal,another_str,resultVal_str from tablename
```

Getting results like this:

```
 col_str                                        getVal   another_str              
'11,12,33,54,1,44'                              '12'    '9,5,4,8,7'               
'11,12,33,54,1,44,10,12,11,12,12'               '44'    '9,5,4,8,7,6,3,5,2,4,2'   
'11,12,33,54,1,44'                              '999'   '9,5,4,8,7,4'             
'11,12,33'                                      '0'     '9,5,4'                   
-----                                           ----      -----                   
-----                                           ----      -----                   
-----                                           ----      -----
```

The columns `col_str,getVal,another_str` came from table and the column `resultVal_str` want to calculate based on remaining three column, 
Logic for `resultVal_str` -

See first record `getVal` having value 12 and `col_str` having 12 at location number 2 then see the location number two in `another_str` is 5, so the `resultVal_str` is 5 and so on. See below:

```
col_str                                        getVal   another_str               resultVal_str
'11,12,33,54,1,44'                              '12'    '9,5,4,8,7'                  5
'11,12,33,54,1,44,10,12,11,12,12'               '44'    '9,5,4,8,7,6,3,5,2,4,2'      6
'11,12,33,54,1,44'                              '999'   '9,5,4,8,7,4'                0
'11,12,33'                                      '0'     '9,5,4'                      0
-----                                           ----      -----                     ---
-----                                           ----      -----                     ---
-----                                           ----      -----                     ---
```

How can i add the next column `resultVal_str` with getting result like above ?

Comment: I can see here in example you have given, that no. of items in col_str and another_str are different. What do you expect when occurence of value in getVal in col_str is beyond range in another_str.  Moreover, what do you expect, if getVal is not present in col_str e.g. row 4 in your data sample.

Comment: Then it should be generate 0 as in resultant table, see above resultant table's `resultVal_str` column.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to fin the position of `getVal` in col_str using `FIND_IN_SET` function.

once you get the position you can find the `resultVal` from same location in `another_str` using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function as:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(another_str, 
                       ",", (FIND_IN_SET(getVal, col_str))), 
                       ",", - 1) AS resultVal_str
FROM tablename;
```

test:

```
SET @getVal = '12', @col_str = '11,12,33,54,1,44', @another_str = '9,5,4,8,7';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@another_str, ",", (FIND_IN_SET(@getVal, @col_str))), ",", - 1) AS resultVal_str;
```

Comment: But how can i implement in above query ?